# W3C Caused by: com.apicatalog.jsonld.JsonLdError: Unexpected response code [429]

Tags: w3c

my name is Tuan, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.apicatalog.jsonld.JsonLdError: Unexpected response code [429].
JsonLdError[code=There was a problem encountered loading a remote context [code=LOADING_REMOTE_CONTEXT_FAILED]., message=There was a problem encountered loading a remote context [code=LOADING_REMOTE_CONTEXT_FAILED].][[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LCgd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpSu7.png)
```

According to my understanding of this error, I seem to have sent many requests to two urls:

- "https://www.w3.org/2018/credentials/v1",
- "https://catenax-ng.github.io/product-core-schemas/SummaryVC.json",
  Can I ask if the w3.org organization seems to have limited my request?
  Can you help me solve this problem? I really need help to complete my work
  Sincerely thank

Can I ask if the w3.org organization seems to have limited my request?
Can you help me solve this problem? I really need help to complete my work
Sincerely thank